# Change cadmin's password

Tags: password, windows-sbs-2008

I dont get something and I need your help. I have some machines under active directory on an SBS 2008. When I install a program a prompot appears to insert administrator credentials. The username I have to enter is cadmin. I changed cadmin's password through active directory and restarted the server but I saw that changes didnt apply. Does it need something else? The machines have also restarted.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look as the services running on the machine ... start/run services.msc. There may be some that are running with the "cadmin" credentials. You may need to change the password in those services as well.

If that doesn't work, look in the event logs (start/run eventvwr.msc).

BTW .. when running SBS, it is better to use the SBS console tools when possible than to use the standard AD tools (like AD Users and Computers).  I don't completely know why, I just know that it seems to be the case.

Comment: I am not sure that this users exists at sbs console list. I wanted to do it from there first :s

Comment: Ok, I found the reason...servers needed to be restarted :)